# Jquery selector with "." "_" not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this input:

```
<input type="text" name="Latitude" id="Latitude" />
```

And with that jquery is setting the value ok:

```
$('#Latitude').val(latitude);
```

But now i need to change the id of the input to RegisterModel_Latitude or RegisterModel.Latitude, so:

```
<input type="text" id="RegisterModel_Latitude" />
```

or

```
<input type="text" id="RegisterModel.Latitude" />
```

But I can't set the value with jquery... I have tried:

```
$("#RegisterModel_Latitude").val(latitude);
$("#RegisterModel.Latitude").val(latitude);
$("#RegisterModel\\.Latitude").val(latitude);
$('input[id="RegisterModel_Latitude"]').val(latitude);
$('input[id="RegisterModel.Latitude"]').val(latitude);
$('input[id="RegisterModel\\.Latitude"]').val(latitude);
```

But none of these are working, so what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: The first option works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Q7tbD/. The ID with `.` is parsed by JQuery selector as a class name, so it won't work.

Comment: Try and check for typos (in the HTML elements/attributes and the jQuery).

Comment: Wait....  what's the problem?  http://jsfiddle.net/HjbCr/

Comment: Mine in jsfiddle, is working too. But isn't working in a MVC3 project using jquery 1.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the soution, changing:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RegisterModel.Address, new { onblur = "codeAddress(RegisterModel_Address.value);" })
```

to:

```
<input type="text" id="RegisterModel_Address" onblur="codeAddress(RegisterModel_Address.value)" />
```

Now is working, thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

The `_` is a valid character for the the id (see @VisioN's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7tbD) for an example).

The `.` denotes a class.  So `$("#RegisterModel.Latitude")` is looking for an element with the id `RegisterModel` and the class `Latitude`.  See my fork of @VisioN's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XFsj5/) for an example.

Comment: Yes, but you can use: $("#RegisterModel\\.Latitude").val(latitude); http://jsfiddle.net/PdE37/

Answer (score 1):

Check variable latitude (var latitude) may be missing

Comment: This is working: $('#Latitude').val(latitude); latitude is not missing.

Answer (score 0):

Wait. If I got it, you want to change the ID, but you're using val instead of attr. Why not:

```
$('#Latitude').attr('id','RegisterModel_Latitude');
```

or

```
$('input[name=Latitude]').attr('id','RegisterModel_Latitude');
```

The val changes the value, but not ID. =)

Comment: No, no, I set the id manually, I want to change the value actually